# Использование GD

Tags: php, gd

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при загрузке на сайт изображения товара, оно становилось нужных размеров, чтобы оно через функцию кроп изменялось до нужных размеров.

Допустим оно было 250x180,а стало 300x300. Сделать необходимо с помощью библиотеки GD, а именно функцией imagecrop(), но так чтобы любое изображение которое загружается - изменялось.

Очень прошу помочь! Буду благодарен.

Comment: а почему просто не задать размеры с помощью `css`?

Comment: дак и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: @Alpha потому что можно назаливать картинок в большом размере  а потом чтобы показать превью по сети будут мегабайты летать вместо килобайт, если  уменьшать средствами css. что очевидно кардинально замедлит отображение контента для пользователя, съест его, возможно, лимитный трафик, увеличит нагрузку на сервер и загрузит его канал.

Comment: @Влад к слову, через `imagecrop()` - это сделать невозможно, данная функция режет изображение, либо накладывает его на большее полотно, именно размер изображение в определенном соотношении она уменьшить не может, вам нужна `imagecopyresized()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Function cropImg():

```
  $pngPath    = realpath ("D:\JaredsPlace\OSPanel\domains\stackoverflow\shark_PNG18835.png");

/**
 * Функция для сжатия с возможным обрезанием изображения.
 * 
 * @param string $imgPath   | Путь до изображения
 * @param int $ratio        | Степень уменьшения изображение (по умолчанию в три раза (было 900 -> станет 300), может варьироваться от 1 до 9)
 * @param bool $save        | Если параметр не задан или имеет значение false, то изображение будет выводиться в браузере
 * @param int $quality      | Качество, может варьироватьтся от 0 до 9
 * @param int $imgWidth     | Ширина изображения (нужно учитывать, что они будут уменьшены в $ratio раз, можно выставить $ratio = 1, и задать желаемые размеры конечного изображени)
 * @param int $imgheight    | Высота изображения (нужно учитывать, что они будут уменьшены в $ratio раз, можно выставить $ratio = 1, и задать желаемые размеры конечного изображения)
 * @param int $cropWidth    | Ширина прямоугольника под изображение (не знаю для каких целей вам это надо)
 * @param int $cropHeight   | Высота прямоугольника под изображение (попробуйте, поиграйтесь)
 * @param int $cropPositionX| Смещение по оси Х
 * @param int $cropPositionY| Смещение по оси Y  
 * @return void
 */
function cropImg (string $imgPath, int $ratio = 3, bool $save = false, int $quality = 0,
                    int $imgWidth  = null, int $imgHeight  = null,
                    int $cropWidth = null, int $cropHeight = null,
                    int $cropPositionX = 1, int $cropPositionY = 0): void {

    /**
     * Если параметр $save не задан, то по дефолту изображение будет выводиться в браузере.
     * В ином случае, создаем рандомную строку для имени файла и сохраняем.
     */
    if (!$save) {
        header ('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    } else {
        $currentDate    = new \DateTime ();
        $currentDate    = date ('Y-m-d', $currentDate->getTimestamp ());
        /**
         * Временное имя файла
         */
        $tmpImgName     = "IMG({$currentDate})";
    }

    /**
     * Проверяем, передан ли путь к изображению.
     */
    if (isset ($imgPath)) {
        /**
         * Если не заданы размеры конечного изображения (пример: 350х500),
         * то получаем их сами и сразу режем в соотношении уменьшения $ratio;
         */
        if (is_null ($imgWidth) and is_null ($imgheight)) {
            $imgAttr = getimagesize ($imgPath);

            $imgWidth   = (int) (round ($imgAttr[0]  / $ratio)); 
            $imgHeight  = (int) (round ($imgAttr[1]  / $ratio));
        }

        /**
         * Создаем новый ресурс изображения.
         */
        $tmpImg     = imagecreatetruecolor ($imgWidth, $imgHeight);

        /**
         * Берем ресурс целевого изображения.
         */
        $newPNG     = imagecreatefrompng ($imgPath);

        /**
         * Если переданы значения высоты и ширины прямоугольника, 
         * для указания размеров создаваемого изображения, то применяем их, если нет, берем их из целевого изображения.
         * (Высота и ширина квадрата, в котором будет размещено ваше изображение)
         */
        $cropWidth  = is_null ($cropWidth)  ? (int) (round (imagesx ($newPNG) / $ratio)) : (int) (round ($cropWidth / $ratio));
        $cropHeight = is_null ($cropHeight) ? (int) (round ((imagesy ($newPNG) / $ratio))) : (int) (round ($cropHeight / $ratio));

        /**
         * Определяем размер полотна (ширина или длинна)
         */
        $cropSize   = ['width' => (int) (round ($cropWidth)), 'height' => (int) (round ($cropHeight))];

        /**
         * Меняем размер изображения с помощью копирования на другое, созданное. 
         * $imgWidth  - ширина результирующего изображения
         * $imgHeight - высота результирующего изображения
         */
        imagecopyresized ($tmpImg, $newPNG, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, imagesx ($newPNG), imagesy ($newPNG));

        /**
         * Передаем ресурс изображения $newPNG и устанавливаем смещение, зачастую они 0-вые (квадрат),
         * X - по горизонтали, Y - по вертикали
         */

        $cropedPNG  = imagecrop (
            $tmpImg, [  'x' => (bool) $cropPositionX ? $cropPositionX : 0, 
                        'y' => (bool) $cropPositionY ? $cropPositionY : 0, 
                        'width' => $cropSize['width'], 
                        'height' => $cropSize['height']
                    ]
        );

        /**
         * Imagecrop может вернуть ресурс или же bool (false)
         */
        if (!is_bool ($cropedPNG)){
            /**
             * Imagepng|imagejpg|imagebmp|etc - выводят изображения в браузер, если задан только один параметр (ресурс изображения),
             * второй параметр необзятальный (путь с именем файла, пример: './example.png'), то данная функция не отрисует изображение,
             * а сохранит его под данным названием по указанному пути,
             * третий параметр - cтепень сжатия: от 0 (нет сжатия) до 9 (макс сжатие).
             */
            imagepng ($cropedPNG, !isset ($tmpImgName) ? null : $tmpImgName, $quality);
        } else 
            imagedestroy ($cropedPNG);
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
cropImg ($pngPath, 1, false, 9);
```

Comment: Евгений, как должен выглядить полноценный скрипт с этим функционалом? И можете рассказать в кратце что тут что значит. Я слаб в php, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: И ещё, как этом можно реализовать в html разметки, чтобы загружаемое изображение изменялось. Допустим через cms modx, загружать фотку товара, она будет изменяться и появляться на фото

Comment: @Влад Ну теперь можно в код не лазить, все регулируется через параметры функции, можно конечно такое количество объектом заменить или массивом хотя бы, но это уже за вами, все вроде работает) удачи

Comment: Спасибо большое!