# Как грамотнее работать с фотографиями в маркетплейсе? PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, big-data

Как грамотнее хранить и выводить изображения товаров в маркетплейсе?

*Мои варианты:*

**1.** При добавлении товара фотки загрузить на сервер, а ссылку изображения сохранить в базу, после чего её вывести

**2.** Просто загрузить в определённый путь, например: /айди_продаца/айди_товара/разрешение/Фотка.расширение

При втором способе получать количество изображений можно через папку и через цикл их выводить.

**Так же важно разделять изображения по разрешениям.**

Возможно есть способ хранить фотографии как-то иначе.

Например сделать файл при обращении к которому (с определёнными GET параметрами) он вернёт нужное изображение, так, если надо можно на ходу сжать изображение.

Не знаю насколько производительно сжатие изображения при каждом обращении.

В моём случае важна производительность. Хранить изображения в нескольких разрешениях нужно для более быстрой загрузки страницы.

Comment: Ваш подход верен, так же можно использовать cdn хранилище изображений, типа cdn cloud.

Comment: @Borislav какой из подходов? Я описал 3 возможных. 1 2 или 3?

Comment: 1,2 (т.к. они подразумевают одно и тоже, подход к реализации немного разный), смысл загрузки изображения на сервер, а там как вы его выдавать будете и осуществлять его поиск для юзера, это уже ваше.

Comment: Про сжать на ходу, можете проверить, подобный ответ уже давал, правда там сама реализация, но отрабатывает со средней скоростью (в прочем, там есть возможность изменения качества, думаю это повысит производительность): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085575/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-gd/1085636#1085636